# Overflow X issue not working on Firefox but does on IE and Chrome so far

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

This is the code: the problem in Firefox is that the scrollbar has no limit in X direction.

Please, open the code in Chrome and Firefox to see the diference in the scrollbar for a better understanding of the problem.

Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="position: absolute; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; height:180px;">
        <div style="position: absolute; left:0px; right:0px; top:0px; bottom:0px; overflow:auto; ">
            <div style="width:40000px">
                <div style="width:150px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:4px; float:left" > </div>
                <div style="width:150px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:4px; float:left" > </div>
                <div style="width:150px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:4px; float:left" > </div>
                <div style="width:150px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:4px; float:left" > </div>
                <div style="width:150px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:4px; float:left" > </div>
                <div style="width:150px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:4px; float:left" > </div>
                <div style="width:150px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:4px; float:left" > </div>
                <div style="width:150px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:4px; float:left" > </div>
                <div style="width:150px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:4px; float:left" > </div>
                <div style="width:150px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:4px; float:left" > </div>
                <div style="width:150px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:4px; float:left" > </div>
                <div style="width:150px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:4px; float:left" > </div>
                <div style="width:150px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:4px; float:left" > </div>
                <div style="width:150px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:4px; float:left" > </div>
                <div style="width:150px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:4px; float:left" > </div>
                <div style="width:150px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:4px; float:left" > </div>
                <div style="width:150px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:4px; float:left" > </div>
                <div style="width:150px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:4px; float:left" > </div>
                <div style="width:150px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:4px; float:left" > </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could be because there is nothing in the divs, put a character in each div and see if it works, also, the divs don't make up the full width, so the scroll bar isn't technically needed to see everything

Comment: As advice, (and you might already do so and this is just because it's an example) but I'd suggest creating a class in your stylesheet and applying it to those divs rather than repeatedly declaring the same width/height/bg/margin in each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no content within your divs?

If you want it to work with no content in them, try adding the

```
display:block;
```

into the css :)

Comment: sorry but this is not working in firefox :(  Even if there is an image in each div, it keeps failing to limit correctly the widht of the scroller in firefox

Comment: Upon looking at what the outter container was doing (the one where you assigned the width) it wasnt aligning properly. So i put a color on it, and floated it left, and its the same in firefox, chrome and ie now, that is, its showing all the 40000px. I actually think, that with this set up, its doing as its supposed to.. I suggest changing your approach. Attached is a JS fiddle of the css'd version. http://jsfiddle.net/NhXvz/3/

Comment: Which approach do you suggest?

Comment: Far too long ago for me to remember this individual case Im afraid. I would of looked for a follow up much sooner.

Answer (score 0):

You have a div with width `40000px` in there, so Gecko is letting you scroll 40000px to the right.  Why wouldn't it do that?  The fact that WebKit doesn't seems like a WebKit bug.